# unable to run service when Date changes using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I create an birthday reminder app. I want to start service at 12:00 in night to scan birthdays of person in Database. I add a broadcast receiver.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But It don't work. I don't why..
here is the code of broadcast receiver .....

```
package com.example.forgetmenot;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "BroadCast Receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        arg0.startService(new Intent("com.example.forgetmenot.BirthdayService"));
    }

}
```

I wanna execute this code when date change. Please Help me. I need this to work to complete my app. thanks...

Comment: are you able to see Toast on Date Change?

Comment: No toast not displaying. if you have any suggestions please tell me.....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> 1. create receiver in Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

> 2. create BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)) {
                Log.e("", "ACTION_DATE_CHANGED received");
             }
         }
    }
```

> 100% working

Comment: But sometimes it is not working when the app is closed.