# how to get every day date change info in my android application

Tags: android, date, datetime

I am new for android application development.

In my application i need to listen the every day system date change in background , How to do this,can any one guide me with code.

your response will be appreciated......

Comment: Check for following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890184/unable-to-run-service-when-date-changes-using-broadcast-receiver and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342859/detect-day-change-event-in-broadcast-receiver-in-android

Comment: @Sumant the above link is helped me  to understanding,thanks for response....

Answer (score 0):

Declare Globle Variable

```
    public static String TODAY_DATE;
```

Just Do below code in your MainActivity in onCreate Method

```
TODAY_DATE = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date());
```

It will return system date every day

Comment: thanks for response,it is helpful for checking present day date. but i need to check  background every day immediate system date change....

Comment: you have to run the service,which periodically check the day and date

Comment: @NageswaraRaoCH why you have to check backgroud, when app start then automatic get date from system DixitPanchal is right to get date. up to you how to determine you in your code

Comment: If you not satidfy then check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758246/android-action-date-changed-broadcast